# Python equivalent of matlabfrag

Tags: python, matlab2tikz

I have been a regular user of matlab for plotting. I use `matlabfrag` to save as `eps` for the plot along with a `tex` file containing labels. This can be rendered with `Latex` fonts after including them in Latex document.

I have started using `python` recently. Is there any equivalent of `matlabfrag` for `python`? I am aware of `matplotlib2tikz` and not exactly looking for it.

P.S: Posted already in stackoverflow, but it is too old to migrate here I believe.

Comment: Might this query find a more natural platform on a python-related site?

Comment: There is no need for `matlabfrag` in Python, `matplotlib` can render labels directly using LaTeX: https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html

Comment: @HenriMenke: Just curious if `matplotlib` generates `eps+tex` files like the `matlabfrag` or it generates only `tex` file and the plot is generated on the fly by LaTeX? I prefer the `eps+tex` option since generating plots on the fly purely with `tex` has overhead during each compilation.

Comment: @Mico: I earlier posted this question in stackoverflow but did not receive any response. Hence posting here.

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi It generates only one PDF file but the labels are rendered in LaTeX.  You can also export to PGF or use plugins like [tikzplotlib](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib).